# Product pages all have meta titles from 2 different pages combined

Tags: magento-1.8, meta-tags, page-title

Running magento 1.8 with a smartwave porto theme.

We cannot figure out where our store meta title & description are coming from...they're not coming from the meta data area on the homepage & they're displaying across the whole website.

Also whatever meta data i add to product pages is just displaying on the end of this default meta title so it's causing meta titles to be very long & repetitive.

There is no "design" in system/configuration and so i can't look there.

My website is http://bit.ly/1BTBIuK

When i hover over the admin panelhen inside it has 33 keywords due to this sort of repetition....the website developer put them in initially but how can i change them myself?

**Reply to comment:**

When i add meta data to the area you mentioned it just adds what i put onto the end of the meta data that is already present.

Maybe the issue is not having "design" in the "configuration" area of my admin panel at all?

Comment: Have you check at admin..>catalog>manage product>each product  meta title &keyword  field

Comment: it's my question but i cant comment due to reputation. I forgot my login also. When i add meta data to the area you mentioned it just adds what i put onto the end of the meta data that is already present. Maybe the issue is not having "design" in the "configuration" area of my admin panel at all?